# event.watch spits out events in random order

Tags: solidity, web3js, go-ethereum

I am watching an event:

```
var events = EthProj.Message({}, { fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'});
events.watch((error, results) => {
```

Inside the event I do this `tempString = ((messages.split(":")[1].split(",")[0] + " (From: " + messages.split(":")[2].split("}")[0]) + ")").replace(/"/g, '');` Which, long story short, makes a string from the event giving the event from the block (i.e. It gives the event made at block 173).

I then set a `<h2>` element's text from each event. When this happens it sets them in a seemingly random order. What can be going on, it sets them from block 0 to the latest block, so how can this happen.

Here is the full code: https://pastebin.com/wGt5kL1Y

```
var events = EthProj.Message({}, { fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'});
            events.watch((error, results) => {
                i++;
                messages = "";
                messages = JSON.stringify(results.args);
                if(i === messageToGet) { 

                    if(messages.split(":")[1].split(",")[0] != '""') {
                        console.log(messages.split(":")[1].split(",")[0] + " (From: " + messages.split(":")[2].split(",")[0].split("}")[0].split("}")[0] + ")");
                        tempString = ((messages.split(":")[1].split(",")[0] + " (From: " + messages.split(":")[2].split("}")[0]) + ")").replace(/"/g, '');
                    } else {
                        console.log("(No included text)" + "(From: " + messages.split(":")[2].split(",")[0].split("}")[0] + ")");
                        tempString = (("(no included text) " + " (From: " + messages.split(":")[2].split("}")[0]) + ")").replace(/"/g, '');
                    }
                    if((messages.split(":")[1].split(",")[0] === undefined) || (messages.split(":")[2].split(")")[0] === undefined)) {
                        return;
                    }

                    if(document.getElementById("Message" + placeToSet) != null) {
                        document.getElementById("Message" + placeToSet).remove();
                        if(document.getElementById("hr" + placeToSet) != null) {
                            document.getElementById("hr" + placeToSet).remove();
                        }
                    }

                    if(document.getElementById("Message" + placeToSet) === null) {
                        var newh2 = document.createElement('h2');
                        newh2.setAttribute("id", ("Message" + placeToSet));
                        var text = document.createTextNode(tempString);
                        newh2.appendChild(text);
                        document.body.appendChild(newh2);

                        var newHR = document.createElement('hr');
                        newHR.setAttribute("id", ("hr" + placeToSet));
                    }
                }                
            });
```

Comment: That sounds like asynchronous action/behavior and you are expecting synchronous. Please show us your code so we can help.

Comment: Here is the code: https://pastebin.com/wGt5kL1Y

Comment: I've added your formatted code to the question. It's best to make it as easy as possible for others to help you. Navigation offsite should not be required in order to assist you. Let's see whether that helps attract answers.